# Как деплоить кафку на миникуб?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

Проблема у меня довольно странная, я заливаю работающий image из докера если быть точнее wurstmeister/kafka , на докере контейнер создается, все работает, связывается с зукипером нормально и все такое. Но вот в кубере выдает ошибку Back-off restarting failed container. Залезая в логи я вижу что [image: Powershell] 
Хотя когда я создаю docker-image через docker-compose файлик такая конфига у меня задана да и локально в докере все окей, с чем может быть связана ошибка и как ее пофиксить ?
[image: То как я деплою сам имедж]

Comment: Как разворачиваете на k8s? Покажите команду и конфигурацию deployment/replicaset

Comment: Я новичек в кубере, не совсем понял вопрос .... Я могу что угодно прислать, просто не пойму что именно нужно

Comment: при создании через `docker-compose` вы указываете env vars, и там есть `KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT`, но когда вы создаете через `create deployment` ничего не указываете

Comment: вам просто нужно запустить один инстанс zookeeper и kafka?

Comment: Тема такая, у меня есть приложение, оно нормально деплоится, проблемы как раз в зукипере и кафке, а как мне указать в create deployment что то , туплю очень сори? )

Comment: Смотрите пример тут https://www.magalix.com/blog/kafka-on-kubernetes-and-deploying-best-practice

Comment: Я думал что при деплое в кубер изображения из докера у меня сохраняются настройки изображения ... Возможно ли так сделать ибо у меня на докере уже собрано приложение и все имеджи работают отлично

Answer (score 0):

Если вам просто нужно задеплоить `Kafka`, которое будет использоваться вашим приложением, то я бы советовал посмотреть в сторону `Helm` - это менеджер пакетов (готовых приложений) для `Kubernetes`, который имеет уже кучу готовых приложений, а также кучу конфигураций, т.е. можно настроить развертывание приложения по себя.

Установите `Helm`: [офф. инструкция](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/).

Установить `Kafka` (от `bitnami`):

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm install my-release bitnami/kafka
```

Это развернет вам `Kafka` со всеми нужными настройками (один инстанс). `Helm` вам напишет по каким адресам внутри кластера `Kubernetes` можно это использовать.

Для вашего приложения вы можете создать `deployment` руками и укажите правильные адреса `Kafka`, это не скожно, я думаю гайдов в интернете достаточно.